# .NET Core projects having different platform monikers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core application. The projects consists of an API layer implemented using Web API and various back-end layers (app services, domain services, data access).

For some projects, the project.json file includes the following monikers:

```
"frameworks": {                                                           
   "dnx451": {},
   "dnxcore50": {}
 } `
```

and other projects use the newer monikers:

```
"frameworks": {
   "net451": {},
   "dotnet5.5": {}
}
```

The reason why these differ between projects is that some projects have dependencies that are not yet compatible with the newer platforms whereas others are not compatible with the older platforms.

Is it possible to have different projects in the same application targeting different frameworks like this? The solution compiles and runs (though only tested using IIS Express) however I wonder if it's likely to cause any issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you keep in mind that ASP.NET Core RC2 is not released yet, this should not cause problems for now.

Once RC2 is out, net4*, netstandard1.* and netcoreapp1.* will be the monikers that will be supported. dnx4*/dnxcore5* and dotnet5* will be retired at that point.